# Change direction of fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I made a game and now I can not figure out how to shoot at where ever you are clicking instead of straight ahead.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
//1
SKSpriteNode *shipLaser = [_shipLasers objectAtIndex:_nextShipLaser];  
_nextShipLaser++;
if (_nextShipLaser >= _shipLasers.count) {
    _nextShipLaser = 0;
}

//2
shipLaser.position = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x+shipLaser.size.width/2,_ship.position.y+0);  
shipLaser.hidden = NO;
[shipLaser removeAllActions];

//3
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, _ship.position.y);
SKAction *laserMoveAction = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:0.5];  
//4
SKAction *laserDoneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
    //NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
    shipLaser.hidden = YES;
}];

//5
SKAction *moveLaserActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[laserMoveAction,laserDoneAction]];
//6
[shipLaser runAction:moveLaserActionWithDone withKey:@"laserFired"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do is find the location of the touch within your view. So you're gonna need to add this into your touchesBegan method

```
 for(UITouch *t in touches) {
    CGPoint point = [t locationInView:<view>];

    // for use in Sprite Kit
    CGPoint point = [t locationInNode:<node>];
    // make the x position of the object being shot
    // equal to the point location
 }
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response but it says "point" is a unused variable

Comment: @user3053675 he's telling you how to access the touch point. You have to take this and incorporate it into your code now. Perhaps adjusting the y position at item 3?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to replace this row

```
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, _ship.position.y);
```

by this

```
CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
```